# Regex PCRE: validate string that does not contains 3 or more consecutive digits

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I've searched the questions but can't find an answer. I need a pattern that, used with php preg_match function, only match strings that does not contains 3 or more consecutive digits, e.g.:

```
rrfefzef        => TRUE
rrfef12ze1      => TRUE
rrfef1zef1      => TRUE
rrf12efzef231   => FALSE
rrf2341efzef231 => FALSE
```

So far, I have wrote the following regex:

```
@^\D*(\d{0,2})?\D*$@
```

it only match the strings that have only one occurrence of `\d{0,2}`

If someone else has time to help me with this, I would appreciate it :)

Regards,

Comment: Your second example is false, is not it?

Comment: @Gábor Lipták: He only wants to check for consecutive digits, so that evaluates correctly.

Comment: couldn't you really simplify this by searching for `/\d{2,}/` and negating the result?

Comment: @poke - `12` seems like consecutive digits to me...

Comment: @poke I can see two consecutive digits in `rrfef12ze1` @Gábor

Comment: @thetaiko: Oh well, from the code he posted it seemed that he still accepts 2 consecutive digits, but not more..

Comment: @poke - indeed - I think OP might be confused with expected results, or describing the problem to be solved.

Comment: yes, sorry, in fact the issue was to match strings that does not contains 3 or more consecutive digits, I'm going to edit my question but poke have found the correct answer :)

Comment: @poke: There is a bit of confusion in the spec. His written word states 2 or more digits, but his test cases have 3 or more. And whether he means consecutive or sequential is also unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/^(.(?!\d\d\d))+$/
```

Matches all characters that are not followed by three digits. [Example](http://regexr.com?2scbj).

Answer (score 2):

Reject the string if it has two or more consecutive digits: `\d{2,}`

Or use negative lookahead to match only if there are no consecutive digits: `^(?!.*\d{2}).*$`

Answer (score 0):

You could search for `\d\d`, which will match on all the bad strings. Then you can adjust your further program logic to correctly react to that.

If you really need a "positive" match on strings that contain adjacent digits, this should also work:

```
^\D?(\d?\D)*$
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there anything stopping you from simply prefixing the `preg_match()` function with "**!**", thereby reversing the boolean result?

```
!preg_match( '/\d{2,}/' , $subject );
```

Is so much easier...

Comment: Depends on whether we are considering his test cases, or his written spec - it satisfies "_...does not contains 2 or more consecutive digits_", but the test cases seem to be 3 or more. And then, looking at the test cases again, he may mean 3 or more _sequential_ digits (ie "**123**" = True, but "**134**" = False).

Comment: In fact I'm using a framework that, in this case, encapsulate preg_match return so I can't just reverse preg_match result. I could have used a callback instead but I prefer the regex approach ;)

Answer (score 0):

If I interprete your requirement correct, following regex matches your valid inputs without matching the invalid inputs.

```
^\D*\d*\D*\d?(?!\d+)$
```

is explained as follows

```
> # ^\D*\d*\D*\d?(?!\d+)$
> # 
> # Options: case insensitive; ^ and $ match at line breaks
> # 
> # Assert position at the beginning of a line (at beginning of the string or
> after a line break character) «^»
> # Match a single character that is not a digit 0..9 «\D*»
> #    Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back
> as needed (greedy) «*»
> # Match a single digit 0..9 «\d*»
> #    Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back
> as needed (greedy) «*»
> # Match a single character that is not a digit 0..9 «\D*»
> #    Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back
> as needed (greedy) «*»
> # Match a single digit 0..9 «\d?»
> #    Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as
> needed (greedy) «?»
> # Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below starting at this
> position (negative lookahead)
> «(?!\d+)»
> #    Match a single digit 0..9 «\d+»
> #       Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible,
> giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
> # Assert position at the end of a line (at the end of the string or before a
> line break character) «$»
```